# Fine-Tuning Large Language Model on PDFs containing Text and Images

Tags: machine-learning, extract, openai-api, large-language-model, fine-tuning

I need to fine-tune an LLM on a custom dataset that includes both text and images extracted from PDFs.

For the text part, I've successfully extracted the entire text data and used the OpenAI API to generate questions and answers in JSON/CSV format. This approach has been quite effective for text-based fine-tuning.

However, I'm unsure about how to proceed with images. Can anyone suggest a method or library that can help me process and incorporate images into the fine-tuning process?
And then later, using the fine-tuned model for QnA. Additionally, I'm confused about which model to use for this task.

Any guidance, resources, or insights would be greatly appreciated.